# What does "A flagging something" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> It might shore up flagging economic growth.
>
> To shore up his flagging popularity.

The first is found in an article about currency devaluation, the second is about some politician embracing the far right.

What does a flagging something mean in general?

Comment: Drooping, limp: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flagging

Comment: @Stephie Thanks a lot, now I understand it and deleted my previous answer.

Comment: waning popularity, or he is less popular than he was before (some point in time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means wavering or drooping.

"Flagging" originally meant "to flap about loosely", much like a flag in a moderate wind. At some point around 1600 it came to mean drooping or wavering, like a flag with no wind. I would say that flagging is not as strong as wavering or drooping, because a flag will always perk right up with the next breeze.